# wsimport for Onvif wsdl - no service definition

Tags: soap, wsdl, onvif

There are several questions along similar line but none answers this definitively.

I'm using `wsimport` to generate code from a .wsdl file ([Onvif's wsdl files](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl)). Running

```
wsimport -keep https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl -extension -Xnocompile
```

outputs

```
At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
```

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892420/6844926) I added this service declaration, locally downloaded the `onvif.xsd`, and `common.xsd`, modified the path specified for these Onvif files, which then generated the code.

Is there a more straightforward way to run the `wsimport` command on each of these Onvif URLs? There are over 20 wsdl files, and I find it silly to manually download, then make the above changes in each file to be able to run `wsimport`.

Answer (score 3):

You should make these changes in your `WSDL` file:

1. add `name="DeviceService"` in line 11 which starting with `<wsdl:definitions...`
2. add

   `<wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
           <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
               <soap:address location="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl"/>
           </wsdl:port>
       </wsdl:service>`

at the end of file after `</wsdl:binding>`

Then run the generating command.

Comment: I understand this is to be done. I would like to avoid making these changes for all Onvif wsdl files - my question specifically is how to avoid adding these lines to all wsdl file.

Comment: I think there is not another choice, these errors come from `WSDL` files which have been uploaded in `ONVIF` web site. It may be company's trick! I tried for about more than 2 weeks to find out these errors.

Comment: That's just a shame. It's very annoying that being an _open standard_, they don't have any open source full usage example. All they've provided is an Application Programmer's Guide and nothing else; and that is almost unusable. Took me over 2 days just to get login to work.

Comment: That works for me, too. Thanks. To automate the replacement process, I developed a linux shell script using "sed" and "grep" commands.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://github.com/onvif/specs/discussions/90. Quoting [Steven Dillingham](https://github.com/steven93921):

> I always defined the service either directly in the ONVIF WSDL file or creating a parent WSDL file that imported the ONVIF WSDLs and defined all the services I needed to generate. I recommend the latter as it is easier when ONVIF publishes updates to the WSDL file you don't need to keep re-adding the service.